# Количество строк

Tags: php

Вот есть у меня переменная которую я вывожу в textarea, вот как посчитать кол-во строк?

Answer (score 3):

```
$lines = explode('\n', $str);
$count = count($lines);
echo $count;
```

Answer (score 3):

Медленный способ. Затратный по ресурсам и не всегда выдает правильный результат

```
<?php
$test = "123\n234234\nrtreg\nregerg";
echo count(explode("\n", $test));
?>
```

Более быстрый вариант:

```
<?php
$test = "123\n234234\nrtreg\nregerg";
echo substr_count($test, "\n") + 1;
?>
```

Вопрос в том, что делать в случае `"\n123\n456\n"` - это две строки или 3 или 4? Код выше скажет 4, но логика подсказывает, что скорее всего три (а первая строка пустая). Но можно вычитать 1, если первый символ \n. Тоже можно сделать и с последним символом.

Answer (score 0):

Разделить количество символов в переменной на количество стобцов в `textarea`.

Comment: Интресно, а кто минусует? Почему все привязываются к EOL (\n) а если в строке не будет переносов, что дальше?

Comment: а если шрифт будет не [моноширинный](моноширинный), то десять i , будет **у**же 9 w. Так что способ неверный.

Comment: @KoVadim, А способ с \n вообще не будет работать, если переносов строк нет, верно? Я не настаиваю, что мой вариант правильный, просто при некоторых условиях Ваш способ работать не будет, а при некоторых - мой.

Comment: почему это  не  будет? нет \n - одна строка.

Comment: Если строка типа 
"wwwwwwww"
Это же уже не будет одной строкой, если ширина textarea - 3 символа. К тому же по дефолту в textarea шрифт моноширинный. По прежнему считаете, что в моих словах отсутствует логика?

Comment: а если у человека в браузеле будет стоят переопределение user style либо увеличненный шрифт, а если вдруг на телефоне откроет?   
тут зависит от того что именно ТС хочет, с точки зрения переменной как тектста -- способ с `\n` вполне подходит, с точки зрения отображения у пользвоателя -- это вообще не на пхп решается...